# Dynamic SQL error for multivalued parameter

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012, dynamic-sql

I have a stored procedure that contains dynamic SQL which one of the parameters is multivalued. On execution I'm receiving the following error:

**Error Message:**

*Incorrect syntax near 'GA'.*

**Stored Procedure:**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetRepositoryReturnsGreaterThanZeroTest]    
                    @States varchar(max) = null
AS

Declare @filters varchar(max)

SET @filters = 'Where PaymentAmount > 0'

BEGIN  
SET @filters = @filters + ' AND (State in ('''+ @States + '''))'

DECLARE @SQLString varchar(max);
SET @SQLString = 'Select 
   [ID]
  ,[State]
 From dbo.Bil_ReturnsRepository ' + @filters

EXEC @SQLString
```

**C# code that populates Parameter States:**

```
 var statesList = "";
            foreach (var item in criteria.States)
            { statesList += string.Format("{0} '{1}'", statesList == "" ? "" : ",", item);}

            dbCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@States", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = statesList });
```

**Value of StatesList:**

```
'GA', 'FL', 'TN'
```

Comment: Have you considered Table-valued parameters? It is safer, easier, and more maintainable.

Comment: **WARNING!** Your stored procedure is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You better change it from using dynamic-sql to use a table valued parameter.

Comment: I would like to try and solve this using the current method shown in the example because I'm hard headed and don't like to give up on trying to resolve a problem. I will also try and modify this to use your suggestion of table valued parameters. I will need to do some research on the table valued parameters to see how to modify this. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On first glance I'd say the line

```
'''+ @States + '''
```

messes it up since this - in your example - would lead to

```
''GA', 'FL', 'TN''
```

Try removing '''

Comment: What do you think will happen if `@States` contains `'GL')';Drop table Bil_ReturnsRepository;--`?

Comment: Yes, code injection might be an issue, but that's another topic! ;-)

Comment: No. It's not. By helping the OP to "fix" the problem created by doing things the **wrong** way you are not helping anyone. If you know your code has problems, the least you can do is write that in your answer.

Comment: The question was, why the incorrect syntax error was thrown! Usually you learn step by step, so if the first approach is passing parameters as string so be it! A redesign to table valued parameters etc. would be the second approach. On the other hand, your comment with the code injection does NOT answer the original post, since a string including ''' in the table valued parameter would lead to an error as well!

Comment: I disagree. As I wrote befote, helping someone to do the wrong thing is not helping at all. If you went to a doctor for treating a pain in your head and all the doctor would do is give you an aspirin, while he should treat an in infection with penicilin, would you say that helped? No more pain, sure, but the sickness is still there...